# Is there a way to specify gradle source sets with a pattern?

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following structure in my project directory:

- subfolder1/src/main/java/...
- subfolder2/src/main/java/...
- subfolder3/src/main/java/...
- ...

Is there a way to tell gradle to look in any folder that matches "src/main/java" for the source directories? I'm trying the following, but it doesn't work:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir '**/src/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: then it's a multi project then?

Comment: You are doing weird stuff, please explain what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you want a [multi project build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) or perhaps you want [multiple flavours in a single project](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours)

Comment: This is actually part of an existing project at my workplace, so a lot of the structure can't really change. I'm adding this sourceSets spec to my own separate build.gradle so that Eclipse can parse the code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this is completely whacky, you can likely use a `FileTree` for this.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs fileTree(projectDir).matching {
                include '**/src/main/java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error (when Eclipse tries to parse this):
Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: directory '/Users/Phillip/projects/MyProject/'. The following types/formats are supported: String, File Instance, URI/URL